# reading in a text file with a SUB (1a) (Control-Z) character in R on Windows

Tags: windows, r, parsing

Following on from my query last week [reading badly formed csv in R - mismatched quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830470/reading-badly-formed-csv-in-r-mismatched-quotes), these same CSV files also have embedded control characters such as the ASCII [Substitute Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) which is decimal 26 or 0x1A.  Unfortunately `readLines()` seems to truncate the line at this character, so I am having difficulty in matching quotes - apart from losing the later fields in these lines!

I have tried to `readBin()` but I can't get it to read this file.  I'm afraid I can't cleanly read this into R to give you an example and I'm having difficulty in creating these in R. Sorry not to be able to demonstrate with a clean example.  Thoughts?

*Update*

Now I'm confused - when I use the code

```
 h3 <- paste('1,34,44.4,"', rawToChar(as.raw(c(as.integer(k1), 26, 65))), '",99')
 identical(readLines(textConnection(h3)), h3)
```

I get `TRUE` which I find quite surprising!

*Update 2*

```
 h3
[1] "1,34,44.4,\" HIJK\032A \",99"
> writeLines(h3, 'h3.txt')
> h3a <- readLines('h3.txt')
Warning message:
In readLines("h3.txt") : incomplete final line found on 'h3.txt'
> h3a
[1] "1,34,44.4,\" HIJK"
```

So readLines() reacts differently when coming from a `textConnection()` and it silently truncates at the SUB character.

I would be surprised if it makes a difference but I'm on 2.15.2 on Windows-64.

*Update 3*

Some vague success in solving this...

```
zb <- file('h3.txt', "rb")
tmp <- readBin(zb, raw(), size=1, n=400) # raw is always of size =1
nchar(tmp)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
close(zb)
tmp
# [1] 31 2c 33 34 2c 34 34 2e 34 2c 22 20 48 49 4a 4b 1a 41 20 22 2c 39 39 0d 0a
rawToChar(tmp)
# [1] "1,34,44.4,\" HIJK\032A \",99\r\n"
```

i.e. if I read in the file as binary and convert to character() afterwards it seems to work... this will be tedious for large CSV files...

Could there be a bug in R in incorrectly detecting a Control-Z as end of file on windows??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I've figured out a solution - because there appears to be a problem reading a Control-Z in the middle of a file on Windows, we need to read the file in binary / raw mode.

```
fnam <- 'h3.txt'
tmp.bin <- readBin(fnam, raw(), size=1, n=max(2*file.info(dfnam)$size, 100))=1
tmp.char <- rawToChar(tmp.bin)
txt <- unlist(strsplit(tmp.char, '\r\n', fixed=TRUE))
txt

[1] "1,34,44.4,\" HIJK\032A \",99"
```

**Update**
The following better answer was posted by Duncan Murdoch to R-Devel [refer](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/33213/match=duncan+murdoch+control+z).  Converting it into a function I get:

```
sReadLines <- function(fnam) {
    f <- file(fnam, "rb")
    res <- readLines(f)
    close(f)
    res
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem when I used read.csv with a csv file that contained the SUB or CTRL-Z in the middle of the file.

Solved it with the readr package (if your file is comma separated)

```
library(readr)
read_csv("h3.txt")
```

If you have a ; as a separator, then use:

```
library(readr)
read_csv2("h3.txt")
```