# Data loss during read.csv in R

Tags: r, csv, import-from-csv

I have a .csv file to be imported into R, which has more than 1K observations. However, when I used the read.csv function as usual, the imported file only has 21 observations. This is strange. I've never seen this before.

```
t <- read.csv("E:\\AH1_09182014.CSV",header=T, colClasses=c(rep("character",3),rep("numeric",22)),na.string=c("null","NaN",""),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem? I am giving a link to my data file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86_a8ltyoL3TzBza0x1VTd2OTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Look at row 22--is there anything strange about it?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Seems there is a messy value at row 22... Can't R just coerce this into a NA value?

Comment: It looks like there are a lot of other rows in the file that will cause problems as well. You could use `fread` in the package `data.table` to read in the entire file. All of the columns will be coerced to `character` due to the non-numeric values scattered across columns 4 through 25, but you will at least have the entire file, and you can just manually clean it up accordingly from there.

Comment: Try `read.csv(text = sReadLines("yourcsvfile"), your_other_arguments_to_read.csv)`, where `sReadLines` is from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15876643/1270695. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '26)'

Comment: @nrussell Error in fread("E:\\AH1_09182014.CSV") : 
' ends field 1 on line 5 when detecting types: -3467,478,18.70,82.20,1626.05,24823.22,0.90,0.00

Comment: When I use `fread("F:/TempDir/AH1.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactor=FALSE)` I get some warnings, but there are no error messages and the data reads in (I renamed the file BTW; it's the same data though).

Comment: @nrussell Mine still reports the same error....weird ...

Answer (score 2):

You have some messy characters in your data--things like embedded control characters.

A workaround is to read the file in binary mode, and use `read.csv` on the text file read in.

[This answer proposes a basic function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15876643/1270695) to do those steps.

The function looks like this:

```
sReadLines <- function(fnam) {
  f <- file(fnam, "rb")
  res <- readLines(f)
  close(f)
  res
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
temp <- read.csv(text = sReadLines("~/Downloads/AH1_09182014.CSV"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Have all lines been read in?

```
dim(temp)
# [1] 1449   25
```

Where is that problem line?

```
unlist(temp[21, ], use.names = FALSE)
#  [1] "A-H Log 1"  "09/18/2014" "0:19:00"    "7.866"      "255"        "0.009"  
#  [7] "525"        "7"          "4468"       "76"         "4576.76"    "20"     
# [13] "71"         "19"         "77"         "1222"       "33857"      "-3382"  
# [19] "26\032)"    "18.30"      "84.80"      "991.43"     "23713.90"   "0.85"   
# [25] "10.54"
```

^^ see item `[19]` above.

Because of this, you won't be able to specify all of your column types up front--unless you clean the CSV first.

Comment: Thanks Ananda. Why my dim(temp) returns a 512 * 24 matrix other than 1449? I just copied your code...

Comment: @Vicki1227, I'm afraid I can't help much more than this. I simply downloaded your CSV and applied this idea to it and got the object described above.... Clear your workspace and start afresh?